# Invalid object name "CAccounts"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, winforms

I keep getting this error:

> Invalid object name "CAccounts".

and the code I have is:

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    // Set ConnectionString.
    String sConSg =
    "CONNSTRING HERE";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sConSg))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(stat.Text = exception.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            SqlDataReader slrr = null;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ActivationCode FROM CAccounts WHERE ActivationCode = " +
                "'" + _activationcode.Text + "'", connection);
            slrr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (slrr.Read())
            {
                if (slrr["ActivationCode"].ToString() == _activationcode.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(slrr["ActivationCode"].ToString(), "AutoOptimise");

                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(stat.Text = exception.Message);
        }
    }

});
thread.Start();
```

Can somebody please shed some light?

Comment: Why are you running a SQL statement AND showing messages boxes on a separate thread?

Comment: I just havent removed the threading code from that particular file yet.

Comment: Are you aware that if your `SqlConnection` fails to open, your code will *still* continue to try to run SQL on it after displaying the message box?

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that, but thanks for pointing it out anyway. I'm just trying to get this damn database stuff to work for the time being

Comment: This is very strange. I need a few coffee's.

Comment: Could this also have something to do with the other question you asked about the syntax error?  These are the same tables, correct?

Comment: I managed to figure out that this part of the code was the cause of that other problem, didn't I say that on that page? I'll go over and see if I did. I probably forgot, haven't slept for couple days.

Comment: THEN GET SOME SLEEP.  :)  The worst program you can right is when your own program (meaning you) can't run.  Hope all goes well.

Comment: Off topic, but pleeeease use a parameter for ActivationCode, not an in-line SQL string, when this hits production.

Comment: Your wish has been granted, Kevin. I know it may seem that I'm just going to release a sh*t sql script into the wild for everyone to take advantage on. But I always do things this way. First I worry about getting it to work - THEN once I've got that sorted, I worry about the rest. I just learn better this way

Answer (score 1):

The table `CAccounts` you're referencing in your select clause probably doesn't exist in the database. Check that.

See a list of possibilities here:

http://web.archive.org/web/20150519073601/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/why-do-i-get-object-could-not-be-found-or-invalid-object-name.html

Comment: Yep. It does. It should, I quad-triple checked. Unless it magically deletes itself right after I create it.

Comment: I read the info on that page, then double-checked. Again. I'm not entering in any wrong info, or anything else they suggested.

Comment: Nope. Double-checked that, too. :P

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest these things:

- check which schema the object `CAccounts` is under. Is it `dbo` or other? Does the user have permissions on that schema?
- login to SQL Server via Management Studio. Use the credentials in the connection string that the code is using. Paste & run the SQL statement above.
- use SQL Profiler to capture/verify ensure the SQL statement as it crosses to your SQL Server. Run THAT as an adhoc query against that SQL Server.
- are there any funny DNS issues? Hosts files? Does this happen during debugging or on the app server?
- is the database server name correct? i.e. localhost versus a named server. Try addressing by the IP address that you expect it to be run at, just for fun, both in your connection string, and via SSMS.

Comment: I've done the first three of your suggestions, however, SQL Server Management studio doesn't seem to like connecting to the databases I have. BUT other applications do. I'm not sure if there are any funny DNS issues, I hadn't thought of that. I'll check that out now. I get these errors while debugging.

Comment: Thanks, @p, I will try out addressing by the IP, too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of CAccounts, I had to label it DATABASENAME.dbo.CAccounts.

So it would be something like:

"SELECT * FROM DATABASENAME.db.CAccounts"

Answer (score -1):

This might work:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.1.12;Initial Catalog=Ibrahim;User ID=sa;Password=1412;");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Ibrahim.EVC_Activation_Val (Date,Dealer,Transaction_ID,Invoice_ID,Mobile_Num,Quantity_LE) values('" + DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd") + "','" + Txtbx1.Text + "','" + Txtbx2.Text + "','" + Txtbx3.Text + "','" + Txtbx4.Text + "','" + Txtbx5.Text  + "')",con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Hi Valian, welcome to Stack overflow. While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.